# Creating a button to change menu

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, tkinter

I have tried to create a simple menu using a class in Python3. I have experimented with creating an initial menu with an 'Other menu' button and then once clicked it would take me to another menu with a 'This is the other menu' button.

However it currently just displays both menus on start-up.

Eventually I want to have an initial menu of 12 buttons that will then redirect to other menus. I can do this by creating a new window but I would prefer to keep it in the same window.

What am I doing wrong in the below?

```
#import the tkinter module
from tkinter import *

#create a new class
class Try(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Try, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid(row = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S)
        #,padx=300
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        #create buttons
        self.bttn1 = Button(self, text = 'Other Menu')
        self.bttn1['command'] = self.create_widgets2()
        self.bttn1.grid(sticky = W+E+N+S) 

    def create_widgets2(self):

        #create buttons
        self.bttn2 = Button(self, text = 'This is the other menu')
        self.bttn2.grid(sticky = W+E+N+S) 

#main
root = Tk()
root.title('Editor')
root.geometry()
root.configure(background='black')

app = Try(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `create_widgets2` method inside the `create_widgets` method when you assign the button's `command` option:

```
self.bttn1['command'] = self.create_widgets2()
#                                           ^^
```

You need to remove the parenthesis so that the `command` option is assigned to just the function object:

```
self.bttn1['command'] = self.create_widgets2
```

Comment: Thank you. It now only shows the initial menu but just keeps adding another button when clicked. How can I replace the 'other menu' button?

Comment: You can call `self.bttn1.grid_forget()` inside `create_widgets2` to have the old button be removed from the window.  To destroy its object, call `self.bttn1.destroy()`.

Comment: `self.bttn2 = Button(self, text = 'This is the other menu')
    self.bttn2.grid(sticky = W+E+N+S) 
    self.bttn1.grid_forget() `
This returns     `self.bttn1.grid_forget()
                           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

Comment: That is not from Tkinter.  You are mixing tabs and spaces in your source file.  Never do this.  You need to pick one and use it consistently..